# Spark Applications name convention

Tags: apache-spark

What is a name convention for a Spark Application defined by:

```
SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("name goes here")
```

which is displayed in SparkUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any name but standard name used by spark is -

```
e.g application_<cluster-timestamp>_<counter>

cluster-timestamp = The start-time of the "ResourceManager"
counter           = Monotonically increasing counter for the application
```

Answer (score 2):

what ever app name you mentioned... same app name will come in the spark ui

in the above example :

```
 val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("name goes here")
      .config("spark.master", "local").getOrCreate()
```

name displayed in the UI is ...

[image]

if we are talking about application id of yarn see [code here](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.8.0-RC0/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-api/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/records/ApplicationId.java#L53-L58),

```
@Public
  @Unstable
  public static ApplicationId newInstance(long clusterTimestamp, int id) {
    ApplicationId appId = Records.newRecord(ApplicationId.class);
    appId.setClusterTimestamp(clusterTimestamp);
    appId.setId(id);
    appId.build();
    return appId;
  }
```

> ***Conclusion*** : There is no correlation in name between appname you
>   mentioned in the sparksession and yarn application id name which is
>   generated by yarn.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is useful, but my question was not about yarn, although it could help someone